# Why is XML::LibXML->toString() showing expected XML but findnodes() finding more XML?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I have this subroutine that is passed in a chunk of xml and tries to locate some elements (using XML::LibXML and XPath):

```
sub new_from_xml {
    my $class = shift;
    my ( $xml ) = @_;

    my $self = {};

    foreach (qw[ width height ]) {
        $self->{$_} = $xml->findnodes("//$_")->[0]->textContent;
    }

    $self->{type} = $xml->findnodes("//type")->[0]->textContent;

    $self->{url} = URI->new( $xml->findnodes("//url")->[0]->textContent );

    return $class->new( $self );
}
```

It's get called from here:

```
sub new_from_xml {
    my $class = shift;
    my ( $xml ) = @_;

    my $self = {};

    foreach (qw[id caption orientation]) {
        $self->{$_} = $xml->findnodes("//$_")->[0]->textContent;
    }

    $self->{alt} = $xml->findnodes('//htmlAlt')->[0]->textContent;

    foreach my $instance ( $xml->findnodes("//instance") ) {
        my $photo =
            WWW::NewsReach::Photo::Instance->new_from_xml( $instance );
        push @{$self->{instances}}, $photo;
    }
    return $class->new( $self );
}
```

What I expect is two `<instance> ... </instance>` blocks that findnodes() returns, then when I loop over I pass the first instance on the first call and the second instance on the second call.

This is what I see in the debugger (I'm in the first subroutine above, WWW::NewsReach::Photo::Instance->new_from_xml).

```
DB<13> x $xml->toString
0     '<instance><width>100</width><height>66</height><type>Small</type><url>http://pictures.newsreach.co.uk/liveimages/Decor-tips-for-guaranteed-unsecured-loans-users.jpg</url></instance>'
```

Okay good that's what I expected.

```
DB<14> x $xml->findnodes("//type")->[0]->textContent
0  'Medium'
```

Wait, what? That wasn't present in the XML shown from toString. Where did this come from?

```
DB<15> x $xml->findnodes("//type")
0  XML::LibXML::Element=SCALAR(0x101d03780)
  -> 4334788352
1  XML::LibXML::Element=SCALAR(0x101cdd5c0)
  -> 4334949168
```

Hmm, so there are two `<type> ... </type>` elements.

```
DB<16> x $xml->toString;
0  '<instance><width>100</width><height>66</height><type>Small</type><url>http://pictures.newsreach.co.uk/liveimages/Decor-tips-for-guaranteed-unsecured-loans-users.jpg</url></instance>'
```

Umm, there's definitely only meant to be one `<type> ... </type>` element. What is going on here?

Why is toString showing one `<instance> ... </instance>` element but clearly the actual XML contains two `<instance> ... </instance>` elements? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//foo` will start searching from the document root. You want `.//foo`